# How to use OR in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

I want to return `Total Sales` for 2019 for `County = X OR City = Y`.
How can I do that?

This returns error:

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[Total Sales]} ON 0,
{[Date].[Date].[Year].&[2019]} ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
{([County].[County].[X]),([City].[City].[Y])}
```

> Two sets specified in the  function have different dimensionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to address the hierarchility and dimensionality of the sets. Use the sample below.

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[Total Sales]} ON 0,
{[Date].[Date].[Year].&[2019]} ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
{
([County].[County].[X],[City].[City].defaultmember),
([County].[County].defaultmember,[City].[City].[Y])
}
```